# What is the "corresponding composition of bordisms"?

Tags: category-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, cobordism

I'm trying to read through [this paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/lee/lee.pdf).  Below is a quote from it found on page 9.

> Indeed, $u(1)$ is the unit of the multiplication map $\mu$ since the corresponding composition of bordisms is diffeomorphic to the identity map on $S^1$

What exactly are the "corresponding composition of bordisms" in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bordism $\mu \circ (u\otimes 1)$ results as the juxtaposition of the "cap" represented by $u$ and an identity map, composed with $\mu$: this is what you want to commute, and why it commutes in $\bf Bord$:

[image: 1]

Comment: I think I get it.  So the cylinder corresponds to the $1$ in $\mu\circ(u\otimes 1)$ and the $u$ is the disk?

Comment: Oh!  Cap as you call it is what I called a disk in my last comment.  So yes, I do believe I see it now.  Thanks!